# AWS S3 Signature not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

Not sure what the problem is with my code.. php and html are seperate in actual page.

My error I get back from AWS is:

**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

```
require '/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$aws = Aws::factory(array(
    'key' => "XXX", 'secret' => "ZZZ"
));


$s3 = $aws->get("s3");
$policy = base64_encode('{
    "expiration": "2016-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
    "conditions": [
        {"bucket": "richqtest" },
        ["starts-with", "$key", "user/rdqrdq/${filename}"],
        {"acl": "public-read" },
        {"redirect": "http://cnn.com" },
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
        {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
        ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

        {"x-amz-credential": "XXX/20160806/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request"},
        {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
        {"x-amz-date": "20160806T000000Z" }
    ]
}');

$secret = "ZZZ";

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $policy, $secret, true));



<form action="http://richqtest.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Key to upload: 
<input type="input"  name="key" value="user/rdqrdq/${filename}" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://cnn.com" />
Content-Type: 
<input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" />
<input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="XXX/20160806/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request" />
<input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
<input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20160806T000000Z" />

Tags for File: 
<input type="input"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="<?php echo $policy ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<?php echo $signature ?>" />
File: 
<input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
<!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
```

Comment: this looks like the way to do it..
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html

but I guess I'll know shortly..

Comment: `$secret = "ZZZ";` ... does that represent your aws secret?  That's not what's used at this step in Version 4.

Comment: yeah, ZZZ represents my aws secret access key.. the documentation above says to add it within the 2. Signing Key section when calculating the signature, though I'm still getting the same error. As far as I can tell everything looks right :(((

The only thing I can think of is to concatenate strings within PHP to construct the policy, instead of having one long string. Might be getting tripped up on blank spaces?

Comment: If you have modified the code, please edit the question.  Correctly implemented, you'll be making 5 different calls to sha256.

Comment: I've actually found a good s3 wrapper called Amazon S3 PHP class. It has a function called __getHash that does what I need. Here is a link to the github: https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class